# RAD sporadic errors - Could not initialize com.ibm.rational.team.client.ui.model.common.ImageManager

Tags: java, initialization, ibm-rad

I am using RAD version 7.5.4 and whenever I am opening the IDE, the following error pops up.

An error has occurred. See error log for more details.
**com.ibm.rational.team.client.ui.model.common.ImageManager (initialization failure)**

Please help if there is any jar needs to be added in the classpath

Stack trace: 
!ENTRY org.eclipse.ui.workbench 4 2 2011-10-24 14:50:47.258
!MESSAGE Problems occurred when invoking code from plug-in: "org.eclipse.ui.workbench".
!STACK 0
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com.ibm.rational.team.client.ui.model.common.ImageManager (initialization failure)
    at java.lang.J9VMInternals.initialize(J9VMInternals.java:140)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Don't connect to clearcase on startup. In order to this,
Go Preferences/Startup and shutdown/
Uncheck Clearcase Remote Client plugin, Clearquest plugin

Answer (score 1):

There seems to be an issue logged about this. See the [IBM site](https://www-304.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?crawler=1&uid=swg1PM38965). You will need an account to see the details.

Also starting RAD with the `-clean` attribute might help ...

Answer (score 1):

Also, one item I would mention if the above (turning off connections on start-up, and adding the clean option), is to CLOSE all open files, and CLOSE all open projects.  Then shutdown RAD/Eclipse, and make sure you restart with the -clean option.   That finally cleared it up for me.   It would seem that there is something about restarting with open projects that causes this even with the start-up switches set to off and invoking clean.